# How to store the access_token secure in the browser with Laravel and JS?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-10

I create an API with Sanctum. If the user register or logged in, the `access_token` is returned with the state of the registration/login procese. On the next step the browser will reload to open the dashboard page.
During this reload, the the information of the `access_token` get lost.

I read a lot and find not secure way to persist the data in the client. Cookie with HttpOnly is not readable for JavaScript to set the `Bearer` with the token.

What is a good and secure way to persist the `access-token` over page-reload?

Comment: So you need to make client-side API calls using this token? Then you will have to store it somewhere, where JS actually _has_ access - so a cookie that is _not_ HTTP only; or session-/localStorage. If you only need it on the server side, to make API calls from there - then you should stick it into the user session.

Comment: have a look at this https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sanctum#api-token-authentication not recommended to use token based auth for web, as sanctum supports session/cookie based auth out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

I work with JSON Web Token(JWT) here, we use the localStorage to save the token in client, is easy and you can before of save  in localStorage encrypt the JWT using a keystring, the only sad history is always you want using the token you need take it from storage and desencrypt to get value.

For get easier we create a Service, he encrypt, save, desencrypt and read.
Is a way.